# Esp32 nodemcu GPIO

Tags: c, arduino, nodemcu, esp32

I am using esp32 nodemcu where I am using 16 GPIO pins in it for turning it HIGH and LOW as per requirement. When I power up nodemcu GPIOs are involuntarily being in HIGH state. I want to keep the GPIOs LOW on booting and only HIGH when I prompt to do it. Is there any simple method to do it . I am using arduino sketch programming.

Comment: the ESP starts with internal pull-ups on to prevent disturbance from floating pins to WiFi

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this function call with these variables. You can call this function at your setup loop.

```
pinMode(inputPin, INPUT_PULLDOWN);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).